# Where is the off switch for the concurrent preview now?

Tags: bug, mathjax, user-interface

I feel like an idiot but I cannot find it. Meanwhile, if the post is long and has a lot of LaTeX formulae in it, and the connection is imperfect, the wysiwyg regime is a non-stop fight. I figured out I can force the page script to stop manually by clicking the browser stop button but I do not think that was the intended idea. Please, enlighten me as to where the good old "one shot preview" option is now...

Comment: I am not really sure, but it might be gone. I am not sure the info is up-to-date but see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/feature-request-user-script-or-option-to-turn-off-instant-mathjax-rendering and also somewhat http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4208/a-prototype-for-incremental-preview-updates (on the good side, the threads offer some solutions, but no 'direct' ones also I have not tried them).

Comment: Well, since this "conveniently" coincided in time with the disappearance of the runtime "disable javascript" option on my favorite browsers, I can't help starting to believe in conspiracy theories :). OK, I CAN program myself when I need it. I only don't understand why the developers of the modern software love the users to engage in (skilled or unskilled) fights with their products so much... Why not just to create something that could be controlled through the front entrance, not through the back doors?

Comment: This is one of the handful of regressions from MO1.0, so I'm reclassifying as a bug though I'm not sure it will get fixed.

Comment: I had a fight with the MathJax preview myself this morning. Astonishing that for more than two years, nobody else complained ...

Comment: Some instructions on a work around are [here](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2660/how-to-turn-off-the-mathjax-preview)