# Can Mathjax preview be switched off?

Tags: support, feature-request, mathjax, markdown-preview

I recently typed an answer with a few formulas in it. While I was typing, my browser constantly reloaded the preview part below the typing window. Because MathJax apparently does three passes over the text, typing became so slow that I could not even read the source code I was typing without some waiting.

Of course, I could just write in some editor, then copy into MO. But switching the MathJax preview off temporarily would be a somewhat nicer option. Is that possible?

The comments on [this](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/616/70808) related question suggest that there are more or less complicated workarounds (I followed the links and could not make anything out of them). If we cannot have a "preview off" button, then maybe we could at least have an entry in the help center that explains how to switch MathJax on and off in the browser?

EDIT: A possible solution is now given [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2660/how-to-turn-off-the-mathjax-preview), see also comments below.

Comment: What did not work about http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/2581/  for you? That is what additional information would you want to have presented?

Comment: I just tried it; it works well for me. Would you find some explication on Bookmarklets in general helpful?

Comment: I now managed to do it myself. Apparently, I have to bookmark some dummy page, then edit bookmark title and address. I admit that I have never seen that trick before. My suggestion would be to place (a link to) this hint somewhere more visible. An extra entry somewhere in the help menu would have saved me one or two hours (plus the time I spent waiting for mathjax renderings).

Comment: Usually one can also manually add new bookmarks. For me it is in the menu I get when I right-click in the bookmark zone (but this is likely  tangential). For the documentation, I agree it could be documented better.  But perhaps rather on the meta site. The help-menu contains not much info about MathJax, as this is not present on all sites, and is mostly not easily editable. I might write it soon.

Comment: I wrote it up here http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2660/how-to-turn-off-the-mathjax-preview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn off the MathJax preview?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2660/how-to-turn-off-the-mathjax-preview)