# How to turn off the MathJax preview?

Tags: support, faq, user-interface, mathjax

The constant compiling of MathJax while composing a post is undesirable for me. How can I stop the MathJax preview?

Is there a way to turn off the MathJax preview?

Where is the button to switch off MathJax while typing a post?

Comment: It might be worthwhile to tag this as faq.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9737) and [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3297) on meta.math.SE.

Answer (score 9):

There is no official feature for this (while it used to be present until mid-2013). For reports about this see [Where is the off switch for the concurrent preview now?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/616/where-is-the-off-switch-for-the-concurrent-preview-now)

However, it is possible to get this functionality using bookmarklets (for further details see below).

The following code was posted by [Jack Schmidt](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3710/jack-schmidt) on [meta.math.se](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2581):

> To pause it:
>
> ```
> javascript:(function(){MathJax.Hub.queue.pending=1;})();
> ```
>
> To turn it back on:
>
> ```
> javascript:(function(){MathJax.Hub.queue.pending=0;})();
> ```

### How to use this?

Preparation:

- Create two bookmarks or favorites (or whatever your browser calls the functionality to save the address of some website), call them for example "MathJax: Off" and "MathJax: On".
- Copy the line of code `javascript:(function(){MathJax.Hub.queue.pending=1;})();` in the field where one usually puts the URL for the bookmark "MathJax: Off" Do the same with `javascript:(function(){MathJax.Hub.queue.pending=0;})();` for "MathJax: On"

Usage:

- When you want to stop MathJax, bring up your bookmark list (if you do not show it by default) and click "MathJax: Off"
- When you want to restart MathJax do the same for "MathJax: On" Note that rendering might not start instantly. Possibly add some more characters to the post to get it started.

Comment: For me it worked well, I hope this works for everybody. Feedback, additions and corrections are most well come. The post is CW for a reason. :-)

Comment: I believe this no longer works?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Firefox as a browser, then you can use the **NoScript** plugin, which allows you to selectively turn MathJax on or off.
For other browsers there may be different plugins that allow control over Java scripts.

Answer (score -1):

Let me try:

$$I\ see\ nothing$$

Indeed, if you position your window so that its bottom sticks out below the screen, then the preview will not bother you. Let's double check:

$$I\ still\ see\ nothing\ at\ all,\ no\ undesirable\  preview.$$
$$Yes,\ it\ works\ for\ me.$$

Comment: The preview does not bother by being visible, but by unbearably slowing down the edit box (for long posts). Positioning it outside the visible screen area will not stop the MathJax script responsible for the slowdown, and conversely, there is no slowdown to be noticed in a two-line example.